Asp.Net Core, how to create a DbContext with ODBC connection
I am new to Asp.Net Core and I used Vertica Database.
To connect to the database, I use the 'ODBC' connection of 'System.Data.Odbc'.
It works to create a request database.
Here is the code syntax:
On the controller :
public class StockController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public StockController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
     
        OdbcConnection conn = new      
        OdbcConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        conn.Open();

        string queryString = "SELECT * from warehouse.tblstocks";

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(queryString, conn);

        OdbcDataReader reader;

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
 }

When I looked at the tutorial, the developers used this syntax with SQL Server:
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext 
 {
     public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions)

       :base(dbContextOptions)

    {}
 }

For the controller :
public class MenuController : Controller
{

   private readonly MenuContext _context;

   public Menu(MenuContext context)
   {
      _context = context;
   }
}

In program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MenuContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));

I believe this is the correct way to implement database logic on Asp.Net Core.
But it works with SqlServer. How I can Do something with ODBC ?
There is a correct way to implement ODBC database logic on Asp.Net Core
Thank you for your tips and your help.

Unless Vertica implements an EF Core provider you are out of luck. SQL is too product specific to be able to use a generic ODBC provider (which doesn't exist).
